# Rename nested column in array with spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given the below json snippet and schema, is it possible to rename the `child 1` in a dataframe?
There are plenty of examples of renaming a nested field (`withColumn`), but nothing on renaming a complex type within an array.

**JSON**

```
{
    "parentArray": [
        {
            "child 1": 0
        },
        {
            "child 1": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

**Schema**

```
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "metadata": {},
            "name": "parentArray",
            "nullable": true,
            "type": {
                "containsNull": true,
                "elementType": {
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "metadata": {},
                            "name": "child 1",
                            "nullable": true,
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "struct"
                },
                "type": "array"
            }
        }
    ],
    "type": "struct"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

### Load the test data

```scala
 val data =
      """
        |{
        |    "parentArray": [
        |        {
        |            "child 1": 0
        |        },
        |        {
        |            "child 1": 1
        |        }
        |    ]
        |}
      """.stripMargin
    val df = spark.read.option("multiLine", true)
      .json(Seq(data).toDS())
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +-----------+
      * |parentArray|
      * +-----------+
      * |[[0], [1]] |
      * +-----------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- parentArray: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |-- child 1: long (nullable = true)
      */
```

### change the column name inside array

```scala
    val p = df.withColumn("parentArray", col("parentArray").cast("array<struct<new_col: long>>"))
    p.show(false)
    p.printSchema()

    /**
      * +-----------+
      * |parentArray|
      * +-----------+
      * |[[0], [1]] |
      * +-----------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- parentArray: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |-- new_col: long (nullable = true)
      */
```